# Git gives merge conflict for simple changes

Tags: git

I have a sample test.txt which is just this one line
`one two three four five six seven eight nine ten`

Now I am having below commits (all are one word changes)

- commit 1: `eleven two three four five six seven eight nine ten`
- commit 2: `eleven twelve three four five six seven eight nine ten`
- commit 3: `eleven twelve thirteen four five six seven eight nine ten`
- commit 4: ..
- commit 5: ..
- ...

Though the commits are of same line the difference is clear, every diff is just replacing single word to another word.

Now here is the problem every time git is causing conflicts in almost all merges or cherry-picks, thou it is easily resolvable.

Are there a git plugin to solve this scenario or a different merging algorithm to try?

I am working on a book editing project and using Git to collaborate changes from people as commits.

Answer (score -1):

You mention cherry picking in your question and this leads me to suspect that this may be the cause of the problem.

In git when you cherry pick a change git create an entirely new commit identical to the original (except it's not the original and has a different hash) Git then basically sees this as a "different" change.

Now if these two identical "changes" get merged together later, git will often times see this as a conflict (particularly if they occur on the same line)  It's not really a conflict when you look at it but from git's point of view it sees two changes that modify the same line coming from two different commits and or commit histories.

This is one of the primary reasons to avoid cherry picking.

I would suggest, merging all outstanding branches together, resolving any conflicts and go forward without using cherry picking.

Without knowing what your specific use case is, it is often the case that your merge strategy of using cherry picking can be replaced by using lots of smaller individual topic branches.